# Reverse proxy on my Linux VPS

Tags: linux, docker, proxy

I have a Linux Server with several docker instance running. it looks like that :

- SSH Port: 22
- Container1 port : 4000
- Container2 ports: 5000, 5001, 50002

Currently, i'm using https://nginxproxymanager.com/, but when I bind domain.extension,it binds all the ports on my server, I want domain A to bind to Container1 only, Domain B to container 2 etc... But I dont want domain A to bind my ssh pôrt and domain B ports

What could I use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer.

I bind my containers on the loopback (127.0.0.1 or localhost) so they are only accessible to my server). Then I set my reverse proxy to 127.0.0.1:port